# Best way to generate a new html/php page for each image uploaded to a directory?

Tags: php, html

Right now I have a page that takes each image in the directory and creates a new link. I would also like to create a new page based off each image in that directory. I'm pretty new to php so I'm not sure what the best method of doing this is.

I have the following code for my current page:

```
//pull each image from directory and display img+name+create link
        <?php
        $dirname = "img/portfolio/";
        $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
        foreach($images as $image) {
        $basename = basename($image, '.jpg');   
        echo "<div class='roundSpacer'><div class='roundImg'><a href='".$basename.".php'><img alt='".$basename."' src='".$image."'/><h2>".$basename."</h2></a></div></div>";
        }
        ?>
```

I was thinking first I need to create a template. Then write a php script to somehow creating a new file for each image uploaded based off that template.

Comment: Why in the world do you want to create a separate page for each image? What's the point? Just parse the URL in the PHP-file, and show the correct image.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I don't think you're fully understanding my question. I have the images above on one page and they're all links. Each image link is going to link to a separate gallery containing images. For example, the artist this site is for has a 'western gallery' they will click on the western gallery image and be taken to the page displaying all the images for that particular gallery. So, the above is the 'gallery links' page. Right now I can just throw an images in that directory and the links are already created. I'd also like to automate the gallery page itself being created.

Comment: Basically, what you want to do is reload the page you have (code above) with the link you have on that page already. It's a piece of cake coding job - make each of the existing links link to the SAME PAGE, with something tacked on the url, like `gallerypage.php?gallery=westerngallery` and then parse that gallery-variable to fetch the content for that particular folder. Then you can just pull in the images in that gallery/folder, and decide what type of HTML you want to use to show them. Most likely you would want a lightbox-type popup to show the full-size images from the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create one page per image, the best way is to create one php page, the template, and take in parameter of the url, the name of your image for example : `mypage.php?image=myImg.jpg`

To pass argument, you have 2 methods : `POST` and `GET`. The best for you is `GET`.

So, the url example that I have shown before follow the `GET` method and you need to get the parameter and display the image (an example for your file) :

```
<?php
    $image = $_GET['image'];

    echo "<img src='path/of/img/directory/".$image."'/>";
?>
```

See `GET` method on [PHP manual - GET Method](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: That's not what I'm really asking for, sorry poorly worded I guess. I have the images above on one page and they're all links. Each image link is going to link to a separate gallery containing images. For example, the artist this site is for has a 'western gallery' they will click on the western gallery image and be taken to the page displaying all the images for that particular gallery. So, the above is the 'gallery links' page. Right now I can just throw an images in that directory and the links are already created. I'd also like to automate the gallery page itself being created.

Comment: You do understand that you can just modify the code you have to incorporate whatever folder you want, right? And thereby load whatever folder / images. I don't think it's us not understanding, I think it's you who lack understanding about how templates, URL attributes and PHP works.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Sorry for the misunderstanding guys. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I looked into the GET/POST methods little further and now it makes total sense. I was stuck in the mindset of only using it for forms. Works perfectly now. Sorry for my noobness :-/